# May I use setters in constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, setter

I've to build a timespan class with a rather complex setting process. There will be several constructors. Is it a bad idea to call a setter in the constructors?

I know I shouldn't call non-private setters directly to avoid problems if the setter gets overwritten in a derived class. I thought of either creating the real setter private and wrap a public setter around and call the private setter in the constructor to avoid having to declare it final.

```
class A {
    public:
         A(sometype data1, sometype data2);

         void setData1(sometype data1);
         void setData2(sometype data2);

    private:
         void p_setData1(sometype data1);
         void p_setData2(sometype data2);
};

A::A(sometype data1, sometype data2) {
    p_setData1(data1);
    p_setData2(data2);
}

void A::setData1(sometype data1) { p_setData1(data1); }
void A::setData2(sometype data2) { p_setData2(data2); }

void A::p_setData1(sometype data1) {
     //Complex validation and calculations
}

void A::p_setData2(sometype data2) {
     //Complex validation and calculations
}
```

Does anyone have best practices?

Comment: I don't see a problem with using setters in a constructor. You're able to reuse code doing this instead of defining the same setter logic in both the constructor and the setter. Although I'm not sure why you have private and public setters. Just make them public if they're public.

Comment: Note: C++11 has brought constructor re-use, so for example you can have `Foo(Radians r): Foo(r.toDegrees()) {}` and delegate all construction logic to `Foo(Degrees d);`. Note 2: your wrappers are useless, what matters is not whether you call a `public` or `private` setter, but whether you call a **purely virtual** function or not in your constructor (or destructor).

Comment: `I know I shouldn't call non-private setters directly to avoid problems if the setter gets overwritten in a derived class.` No problem at all. The dynamic type of the class is _this type_ in the ctor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding

> “I know I shouldn't call non-private setters directly to avoid problems if the setter gets overwritten in a derived class.”

This is largely not a problem. Even with virtual setters, the definitions used when constructing a class `A` are the ones for dynamic type `A`. C++ is safe that way, as opposed to Java and C# (where you risk that a virtual call ends up in derived class code before the base class invariant has been established, and bang).

Regarding best practice, it is to be critical of setters and getters. They do have a purpose in a language with introspection, where e.g. "designer" tools can use them, but not so much in C++. So, best practice is to always ask, do I really need them, can I design some other way (e.g. `move` instead of `setxy` (which may not sound very different, but consider a call from a constructor – `move` doesn't make so much sense during construction)).

Comment: In my timespan class the setters are primary used by deserialization methods which read lots of different time formats and set different member variables after which some re-calculation of inner values has to be done. I don't think there is a better aproach to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it a bad idea to call a setter in the constructors?

No - using setters inside your constructors allows you to reuse the setter logic without defining it in both the setter method and the constructor. This means that you would only need to make changes in one place instead of in both the setter and the constructor.